# Mock AxiosInstance. Want to get return in only one test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs

My `api.ts` file

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333/',
})
```

My `react-page.spec.tsx` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { act, cleanup, render, RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Companies } from '../../../../modules/companies/pages/companies'
import { Company } from '../../../../@types/company.type'


let companiesPageElement: RenderResult

const companies: Company[] = [
    {
        _eq: 'id-company-1',
        logo: 'https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/a19vkjSUoD4hVV0djOpSLw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTEyMDA7aD02Nzc-/https://s.yimg.com/os/creatr-uploaded-images/2020-07/20e95610-d02d-11ea-9f0c-81042fd4c51a',
        name: 'Casas Bahia',
        manager: 'Daniel Ribeiro',
        status: 'late'
    }
]


const mockedAxiosGet = (...args: any) => jest.fn(...args).mockReturnValue({ data: companies })

jest.mock('../../../../api', () => {
    return {
        api: {
            get: (...args: any) => {
                return mockedAxiosGet(...args)()
            }
        }
    }
})

describe('<Companies />', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            companiesPageElement = render(<Companies />)
        })
    })

    it('should be able to render correctly the page', async () => {
        // It's a test that use the mockedAxiosGet as all other tests
        })

    it('should be able to go to Create first company page if no companies has found in database', async () => {
               // It's the test that I want to change the api.get return value
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup()
    })
})
```

#### Need to

I want that when I test my SECOND test, the jest renders the Companies page with a new value. Actually, the value is a empty array ([]).

I tried to rerender component inside the `it` function with a new `api` mock.

I Want to implement a specific result to my second test.

Comment: Include errors from attempts

Comment: Hey man! I solved this using the jest-mock-axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `jest-mock-axios`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).